# CUDA fft 1d different results from MATLAB fft

Tags: matlab, cuda, fft

I want to use GPU to speed up my matlab program but I find out a problem. 
The fft result is different from CUDA to matlab. 
I have tried many time but can't solve it. 
So I come here for help.

The original data: [name:cj1;size:1*8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT5dF.png)

And in matlab use the code:

a1=fft(cj1)';

Get the result:
[the fft result of matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGt9J.png)

And cuda code:

```
cuFloatComplex *idata_m;
idata_m = (cuFloatComplex*)malloc(M * sizeof(cuFloatComplex));
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    idata_m[i].x = initA[i];
    idata_m[i].y = initB[i];
}
cuComplex *dev_test;
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_test, M  * sizeof(cuFloatComplex));
cudaMemcpy(dev_test, idata_m, M * sizeof(cuFloatComplex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cufftHandle plantest;
cufftPlan1d(&plantest, 8, CUFFT_C2C, 1);
cufftExecC2C(plantest, dev_test, dev_test, CUFFT_FORWARD);//forward
cuComplex *test_out;
test_out = (cuFloatComplex*)malloc( M * sizeof(cuFloatComplex));
cudaMemcpy(test_out, dev_test, 8 * sizeof(cuFloatComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

[the input data is the same to the original data in matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VoSZ.png)

[the fft result of cuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPl1m.png)

the inserest thing is these two result are very similar but in the wrong order.
So what can I do to make the result the same to the result of matlab?

Comment: Please, this should be  basic: do not put images of data/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imaginary part of the input data used with the CUDA code is the negative of that used with Matlab. So you really are computing the FFT of the complex conjugated input, which [inverts the order of the result](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23733/conjugation-in-fourier-transform). To obtain the same results with CUDA you should be using the same input.

Also of note, in Matlab, the `'` operator computes the complex-conjugate transpose, so you probably want to compare your CUDA results with `a1=transpose(fft(cj1));` instead.

Comment: Or use `.'` for transposing.

Comment: thanks for @SleuthEye,I import the data from matlab directly and I didn't notice the imaginary part that was negative of that used with Matlab. Now I get the right order. Thank you again!!!